# Disable marking files in JBoss 7.2

Tags: jboss7.x, marker

Is there any way to disable marking files in JBoss 7.2?
I deploy/undeploy my war using jmx, when undeploying the war is marked with ".undeployed" even if i deploy it it keeps the same marker. The problem is that when i restart the server the undeployed files can not be redeployed.

Any other suggestion is welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove deployment-scanner subsystem, this why deployments folder wont be even consider for deploying.
And you can use CLI/console/mgmt api to do deployments.

you can remove deployment-scanner subsystem by removing it from standalone.xml
or by running

```
/subsystem=deployment-scanner:remove
reload
```

in CLI.